# Google API Client Library for .NET - Missing documentation

Tags: c#, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-client

I'm trying to generate [page views](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages%20/) and [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events%20/) from an ASP.NET MVC application using the Google Analytics functionality available in the library.

The documentation seems to be lacking, and I am unable to understand how to send page views and events. Within a controller that returns a `PartialViewResult`, I need to send a page view to the Google Analytics service.

So far I've only found two examples of how to use their library

- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch

However these are for various other API's not Google Analytics. For example, in the Calendar API example there is: `calendarService.Events.Insert( event title, event description, time and date etc)`which is then used to add a new entry to user's Google Calendar.

For example, I can not simply do:

```
Analytics analyticsService = new AnalyticsService();
analytics.PageViews.Send(client id, user browser, date time, etc);
```

**My question:** How do I actually use the Google Analytics API to send a page view in a similar manner to the Calendar API? Where are the appropriate methods/classes for this?

Comment: Are you trying to send data to Google Analytics or are you trying to get Data for analytics, if it is the latter the Calendar API can be used very similarly to the Analytics API. In the developer console you'll need to enable the Google Analytics API, and you will of course need to use the correct scopes.